# Code sharing on IOS and Android mobile apps using C++ or Java

Tags: java, android, c++, ios

Are there any libraries or methods that would make sharing code between C++/Java and IOS/Android easier? I realize we have JNI and IOS can use C++ pretty much directly, but it seems like it could be easier.

Microsoft Universal Windows Apps and Chrome Apps are (sort of) doing this.

Open Source is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html) a lot. With the latest versions, you write your whole application in C++, using Qt toolkit, and you can compile it targetting PC, Android and iOS (never tested this last one). If you need to call some SDK functions not available in Qt API, they provide wrapper objects to create and manipulate Jni objects, and you can also execute pure Jni code (loading a java file) if you want to.

Comment: Titanium is not Java/C++, but Qt Creator is a nice option. I am looking for something that works at a lower level than Qt Creator so I have complete control over UI - but still good option. Thanks.

Comment: You are right about Titanium, removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to share Java, you could try to use this: https://github.com/google/j2objc. I am not certain I'd say that it is easier than using C++. Each option will have some challenges. The downside to j2objc is that it is a translation of Java to Obj-C. So if there is a bug in it (note the comment in the desc which indicates it is between alpha and beta quality), you will need to figure out how you deal with it.

Admittedly, I have only done limited Android dev, and for that, it used the NDK and had a C++ lib which was shared between iOS and Android. I've also developed apps for iOS that were probably 95%+ C++.

BTW, your question is actually a bit vague. If you are talking libs, you should specify what areas you are looking to solve for. Your solution will vary based on your goals.

Comment: Thanks I've seen another one of these Java to ObjC compilers. http://www.robovm.com/. Seems they are both fairly popular though robovm seems a bit more mature at the moment. I realize the question is a bit vague. I'm trying to come up with a general app development methodology which isn't as restrictive as current commercial products, using "bottom up" instead of top down. E.g. sharing low-level code vs. say, Javascript/HTML5.